# Google Analytics v3.2 requires Mobile App Property, killing legacy properties

Tags: ios, google-analytics, universal-analytics

We implemented Google Analytics v1 years ago, when there was no mobile app property, things were just website properties.

Given that Universal Analytics is coming, we decided to switch over the latest iOS GA SDK (v3.2). I was unable to get any data collected in my existing properties, and I was able to narrow it down to the fact that my legacy properties are website properties. If I force it to use a newly created Mobile App property things work fine, but it will not work at all with the legacy properties.

Is there anyway to get Google Analytics v3.2 SDK to work with the legacy properties? They have a lot of data that we would like to keep integrated going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I can get this to work with my existing property, by creating a new view (profile). Apparently, the view(profile) that we have had for years is something like a website view, and will continue to receive the data from the older v1 SDK of the app out there that are posting to it. But I can also create a new view(profile) with "Mobile app" that will get the data from the v3.2 SDK.

[image]

Unfortunately this means that I have to add manually up two different view to get my complete picture. I renamed the existing view "legacy" and named the new view "mobile".